# Why raises a shift in $d$ an area $E_{1}: ax+by+cz = d$ by $\Delta d \cdot |\vec{n}|$?

Tags: linear-algebra, geometry

It might exist an obvious answer, but I do not understand this reason in the following phenomena.

You are given an area:

$$E_{1}: ax+by+cz = d, \vec{n}=\begin{bmatrix}a\\ b \\c\end{bmatrix}$$

Why does a change in $d$, $\Delta d$ heightens the area by $\Delta d \cdot  |\vec{n}|$ so that for every point $P_0$ of the old area, the new point is given by:

$\vec{OP_1} = \vec{OP_{0}} + \Delta d\cdot \vec{n}$

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Consider the following way of looking at area $E_{1}$.
$$E_{1}=\{x+\frac{d}{\|n\|_{2}^{2}}n\in\mathbb{R}^{3}:x\perp n\}$$
i.e. $E_{1}$ is the plane of vectors orthogonal to $n$, raised by $\frac{d}{\|n\|_{2}^{2}}n$.
One can easily see that indeed if $x=(x_{1},x_{2},x_{3})$ and $x\perp n$, then
$$a(x_{1}+\frac{d}{\|n\|_{2}^{2}}a)+b(x_{2}+\frac{d}{\|n\|_{2}^{2}}b)+c(x_{3}+\frac{d}{\|n\|_{2}^{2}}c)=\langle n,x\rangle+\frac{d}{\|n\|_{2}^{2}}\langle n,n\rangle=d.$$
Therefore any change in $d$ will raise or lower the plane alongside vector $n$.

I hope this perspective makes it more clear what is going on. Let me know if anythings unclear.

Comment: I am sorry, but I do not understand this notation:
What do the {} mean and what is x? What does the bracket < > mean?
Thank you.

Comment: The $\{\ \}$ notation is used to denote a set. For example $\{1,2,3\}$ is the set containing 1,2,3. $$E_{1}=\{x=\begin{pmatrix}x_{1}\\ x_{2}\\ x_{3}\end{pmatrix}\in\mathbb{R}^{3}:ax_{1}+bx_{2}+cx_{3}=d\}$$ is the set containing all vectors $x$ satisfying the conditions after ":", in this case the equation you used. The bracket notation $\langle\cdot,\cdot\rangle$ denotes the inner product, i.e. $\langle x,y\rangle=\sum^{n}_{i=1}x_{i}y_{i}$ for vectors $x,y\in\mathbb{R}^{n}$.